# change book fontsize

Tags: fontsize, books

My supervisor asked me to change my thesis fontsize, ONLY the fontsize, not the font type. I don't know why nothing work. 
I tried:

```
    \documentclass[13pt, twoside, openright]{book}
```

but it seems to keep the 10pt fontsize. This is part of my code:

```
\documentclass[13pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\linespread{1.3} 
\usepackage[textheight=\textheight,textwidth=\textwidth,bindingoffset=3cm,vcentering]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sectsty,lmodern}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{media9}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bib/references.bib}

\graphicspath{ {img/} }
\chapternumberfont{\fontsize{20pt}{18pt}\selectfont}
\chaptertitlefont{\fontsize{20pt}{18pt}\selectfont}
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2pc plus 2pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[begintext=“, endtext=”]{quoting}
\quotingsetup{vskip=2pt}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\usepackage[citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    bookmarks=true
}
\urlstyle{same}


\input{titlepage/Titlepage-Generic-Config}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\input{titlepage/Titlepage}
{
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
  \clearpage
  \tableofcontents 
}

\mainmatter
\chapter*{Abstract}
...
\newpage
\printbibliography[keyword={biblio}, heading=bibintoc, title={Bibliography}]
\newpage
\printbibliography[keyword={site}, heading=bibintoc, title={Sitography}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: default supported font sizes in `book` are 10pt, 11pt, and 12pt.

Comment: Try `12pt` instead. `13pt` is not a valid option.

Comment: I've already tried both 11pt and 12pt, it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: @Jojo - If setting `11pt` or `12pt` instead of `10pt` (the default for the `book` document class) changes nothing, then something may be very wrong with your TeX installation.

Comment: Is there a class different from book with the same fontstyle but with a larger fontsize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memoir` class (a superset of the `book` and `report` classes) provides options for font sizes ranging from 9pt to 60pt.

Regarding your MWE I couldn't run it properly because of missing `titlepage` files. However, ignoring those, changing the class fontsize option between 10pt and 12pt gave me, after I had added some normal (lipsum) text, different font sizes in the document.

I also ran my edited version of your MWE with the `memoir` class

```
\documentclass[14pt, twoside, openright]{memoir}
```

which can be simplified to

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
```

as `twoside` and `openright` are among the default options. It did come up with an error that `The secsty package does not work with this document class.` The `memoir` class provides its own methods for `secsty` like things.